# Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, now terminal won't open

Tags: gnome-terminal, 15.04

I can't get terminal to open at all after updating to 15.04. I've read it is because of the custom locale. How do I change this? Thanks

Comment: Give us the error message.

Comment: there i no error message, it just attempts to open when i click on it and it stops trying after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changing the locale actually fixed it.

You can change the locale in `/etc/default/locale`.
You can try setting the contents of that file to:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US"
```

which should work. If that actually works you can then try your preferred locale.

Be sure you are using a valid locale (I, for instance, was missing the .UTF-8 part).

To apply the changes made I would suggest rebooting, but someone else might be able to give a better alternative.

Comment: Or using SSH/Terminal:

`sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US`