# Terminal doesn't start after editing locale file

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, xterm

gnome-terminal doesn't open after I edited locale file here `/etc/default/locale` and I don't have xterm or any other Terminal app installed to see if it runs.

Same problem reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114856/terminal-does-not-start-how-to-fix-it) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613582/terminal-wont-launch-after-upgrading/634161#634161)

I just need to edit the locale file and everything will be back in order, or in this case delete a custom file that I created in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US_custom` using [this guide](http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/12/change-the-week-start-day-in-ubuntu/) to change the week start day on Ubuntu.

I tired finding ways to get elevated privilege without Terminal -- to no avail.

It's like you can't do anything without a Terminal on linux, I'm stuck,
I can't install anything, can't sudo run any app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I created a custom locale file here `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US_custom` and then in `/etc/default/locale` file I had added `"LC_TIME="en_US_custom"` to it, this was making a problem.

Do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and you can type in your commands on TTY that just opened, to switch back to your screen do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

You will be prompted to enter your username now, type it in and hit Enter then type in your password and hit Enter, now you can run commands.

So I ran the following command:

`echo 'LC_TIME="en_US.UTF8' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/locale`

And I re-logged and everything was back to normal.